# ADFS2.0 with kerberos configuration

Tags: internet-explorer, kerberos, adfs2.0, spring-security-kerberos

I am working on implementing the windows Integrated authentication using ADFS 2.0 with kerberos

I had go through the per-requisites
configure windows Server ADDS, ADFS2.0 ,DNS, running on some xyz.com domain

I had one windows client connecting to windows server xyz.com domain

and Spring-security-saml2-sampl application on Linux env

all this domain are connected using VLAN.

For enabling windows authentication I had configured IE settings 
enable windows Integrated authentication, adding local intranet configuration

required.
I had refer this link:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/kerberos/118841-configure-kerberos-00.html

As per kerberos  configuration on windows server I had configured

```
    setspn -a HTTP/adfs01.xyz.com <ActiveDirectory user>

    setspn -a HTTP/adfs01 <ActiveDirectory user>
```

in my windows Client application I can see I get kerberos  tickets:while running

```
   klist tickets
```

but for while to spring-security-saml2-sample application, I am not able to authenticate

getting windows prompt again and again .and failed

what I need to configure for enable ADFS with kerberos ,

Thanks

Comment: I wonder how this is related to ADFS and spring-security-saml2-sample application.

When using Spring SAML2 then it acts as the SAML Service Provider, authentication is performed on the IdP side, which is ADFS.

There is no Kerberos service ticket needed to access SAML2 integrated app.

I would say you either use SAML2 or Kerberos (via SPNEGO) to achieve Web-based SSO.

Comment: while doing windows integrated authentication using this spring-security-saml2-sample webapp, browser should automatically get kerberos ticket from windows server.while processing saml request -response for authentication....For my case some how I am not able to to windows integrated authentication,I get browser continuously prompt for user and password in IE browser

Comment: also if I remove In IE settings Windows integrated configuration ie. unchecked Enable Windows Integrated authentication I am able to get SAML assertion from ADFS 2.0 service

Comment: most likely because IE is sending NTLM token, which is also handled by ADFS IdP, which then sends SAML AuthResponse to Spring SAML SP.

Authentication itself is out of scope of SAML, SAML is standards-based WebSSO

Comment: Just use SAML trace plugin and you can follow the SAML protocol flow (if some front-channel binding is used)

Comment: for tracing I had used fiddler,I can see saml assertion return from ADFS server, after resolving my issue, by setting proper SPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figure out my issue by setting SPN(
service principal name ) to the user of ADFS2.0 logon account ,instead of setting spn on random account.
refereed this link :

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Cookbookcol_Setting_up_ADFS_for_integrated_Windows_authentication_lprIWArpr_

and my IE settings:

Enabled **windows Integrated authentication**.

Put ADFS  server ie windows server:  in  local intranet sites

In local intranet setting **-->** custom level **-->** Added user Authentication **:** **Automatic logon in Intranet zones**

Comment: This is working in IE but not for chrome. Any idea?

Comment: For chromse "system logon credentials" (Kerberos authentication mechanism)

To configure chrome you need to start  application with the following parameter:

auth-server-whitelist - Allowed FQDN - Set the FQDN of the IdP Server.Example:

chrome --auth-server-whitelist="*aai-logon.domain-a.com"

Comment: check post link might help   https://serverfault.com/questions/823307/configuring-google-chrome-to-connect-to-ad-configured-with-kerberos-and-using-ad

Comment: didn't work. --auth-server-whitelist parameter is obsolete in latest chrome versions. Actually, chrome uses IE settings, but somehow it is not working.
Also checked with editing registry entries as stated in 3rd answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800938/how-to-enable-auto-logon-user-authentication-for-google-chrome