# How to bypass or intercept the Authentication Required dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, intranet

Is there a way to bypass or intercept the "Authentication Required" dialog in C# so that it automatically authenticates the user on an intranet site?  The dialog I'm referring to is the one indicated below:

[image]

At present I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 intranet site and have no idea how to stop this dialog from popping up using C# code.

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: For Chrome, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800938/how-to-enable-auto-logon-user-authentication-for-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

To bypass do this:

1. Select project in solution explorer
2. Right click and go to properties (or press F4)
3. Set Allow anonymous access to enabled (enabled, allow or whatever the option was).

The problems originates to not having the site added to intranet. You can do that too but the above makes everything easier. Anyway:

Chrome:
Chrome > Options > Under the Hood > Change Proxy Settings > Security (tab) > Local Intranet/Sites > Advanced.

IE:
[This](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-add-trusted-sites-internet-explorer)

Firefox:
[This](https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/1032092)

Comment: Hi Liquid Core I set the "Anonymous Authentication" for the project to "Enabled" as you suggested but it still asks me for authentication when running the project :-|.

Comment: @TimothyKruger then try to add the site to the intranet.

Comment: @TimothyKruger try also this:
Disable anonymous access and just use 'Integrated Windows Authentication'

In Internet Explorer go to Tools -> Internet Option -> Security -> Custom Level -> Scroll the bottom and select "Automatic Login with current user name and password”.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer and comments, but the reason for my original post was to try and avoid making browser specific changes.  But alas it seems like I'll just have to do this after all :-(.